# Property 'userId' does not exist on type '{ docId: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, use-effect, react-proptypes

This warning comes up on the firebase.js filter line-11. I'm following a tutorial, where I'm supposed to store users in a firebase collection. I'm getting profiles null on the console when I try to pull the userId's for profiles that follow the current active profile from firebase:

firebase.js

```
export async function getSuggestedProfiles(userId, following) {
    const result = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .limit(10)
    .get();
    
    return result.docs

    .map((user) => ({ ...user.data(), docId: user.id}))
    .filter((profile) => profile.userId !== userId && !following.includes(profile.userId));

}
```

Suggestions.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";
import { getSuggestedProfiles } from '../../services/firebase';

export default function Suggestions({ userId, following }) {
    const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function suggestedProfiles() {
            const response = await getSuggestedProfiles(userId, following );
            setProfiles(response);
        }
        
        if (userId) {
        suggestedProfiles();
        }
        console.log('profiles', profiles) 
    }, [userId]);


     return !profiles ? (
         <Skeleton count={1} height={80} className="mt-5"/> 
    )   : profiles.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="rounded flex flex-col">
            <div className="text-sm flex items-center align-items justify-between mb-2">
                <p className="font-medium">Suggestions for you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )   : null;        
    
}   

Suggestions.propTypes = {
    userId: PropTypes.string,
    following: PropTypes.array
}
```

Comment: Where do `following` and `profiles` in the `useEffect((following, profiles) => ` come from?

Comment: Actually those are not supposed to be there sorry about that mistake.

Comment: No need to apologize, but please ensure we have the real code that reproduces the problem. As it stands now, the error most likely comes from `following.includes`, and it is unclear where `following` is supposed to get its value from (which is then also the likely reason for the error you get).

Comment: Alright the mistake there led to the OP but I see it's no longer there, however I still cannot console.log the profiles, I'm getting warning on the firebase file that "Property 'userId' does not exist on type '{ docId: string; }'"